# background-image property is not showing the image in css

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I was trying to put background image but it is not showing.

```
.jumbotron{
   background-image: url("/src/assets/shop1.png");
   background-size: cover;
}

<div class="jumbotron">
   Welcome to Home Page
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps the path is not correct? Go check what your browser console has to say.

Comment: exactly i have to remove slash(/) before src then it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background image will look at the height and width of the div. Please follow the code to see the image.

```
.jumbotron {
   background-image: url('https://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[Working demo](https://codepen.io/sibabrat_swain/pen/YzwzVbj)